# Manipulating HTML from Dart

Tags: html, dart, popupwindow

I open up a popup window with a pre-existing html file and then I'm trying to change the text of some elements (spans), but it's not working. A simplified example is here:

```
Window win;

main() {
   win = window.open("mypage.html", "WindowName", "width=500,height=500");
   win.onLoad.listen(winLoaded );
}

winLoaded( e ) {
   // a span with the id 'span-id' pre-exists on the mypage.html
   var span = doc.getElementById("span-id");
   span.text = "This text never shows up.";
}
```

Also, I previously tried using querySelector(), but it couldn't find the span at all.

*** I forgot to add: It works in Dartium, but not when I publish out and view in other browsers.

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Dart [tutorial](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/connect-dart-html/) there is an example:

`querySelector('#RipVanWinkle').text = 'Wake up, sleepy head!';`

Your code should be:

`var span = querySelector('#span-id');`

Couldn't test the code now, but I think you are missing the `#` in front of `span-id`.